# vulnerabilidades con plugins de wordpress desactualizados?

Tags: wordpress, plugin, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

Hay algún riesgo de tener un plugin como por ejemplo "Cookie Law Info" que está totalmente desactualizado, ya que se dejó de actualizar hace 2 años? Puedo tener alguna vulnerabilidad en cuanto a este tipo de plugins?
Y con los temas?

Comment: No es una pregunta como demasiado amplia? o basada en opioniones? la respuesta podria ser si, pq le encontraron problemas. Si porque cambio la version de wp y tal vez ya no funcione igual. No, porque no hace nada interesante. No se, porque habria que verlo caso por caso..

Comment: La respuesta es definitivamente **Sí**. Siempre que instales algún plugin de WP observa el tiempo que tiene sin actualizar. Si tiene más de seis meses sin actualización, es una mala señal. Con los temas pasa lo mismo. Tanto los plugins como les temas son de los puntos más vulnerables de WP. No tenerlos actualizados puede suponer que alguno de ellos tiene una puerta abierta para los intrusos. A ello se agrega el hecho de la infinidad de programas desarrollados para encontrar vulnerabilidades en WP. Yo reviso en mi hosting a veces la cantidad de intentos que se registran en el log... es enorme.

Comment: Un plugin tan simple como el mostrar las politicas de cookies puede ser una vulnerabilidad?

Comment: Sí puede serlo. En cualquier código, con una sola línea mal escrita se te pueden colar. Eso no tiene nada que ver con la extensión o funcionalidad del plugin. Suponte que los creadores implementaron código usando alguna función de la cual se descubrió más adelante un agujero de seguridad. Si el plugin no se actualiza mediante el uso de una función nueva... por esa sola función se te cuelan en el sistema.

Comment: Y por que no usas este: [link](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/eu-cookie-law/) (actualizado hace 5 días) ???

Comment: Por ejemplo solamente hoy, en el log de mi sitio se han registrado 22 intentos de ataque de este tipo: `msg "Wordpress and Joomla Brute RBL...`  y si voy a las estadísticas, hay más de una decena de errores 404, cuyas direcciones son intentos de acceder a archivos con la extensión `.php` que podrían tener una vulnerabilidad. Si el boot que lanza esas peticiones encuentra el archivo vulnerable... podría entrar en tu servidor y hacer todo lo que la vulnerabilidad le permita.